# Mysql uses the Yearweek function to retrieve last week's data, New Year's problem

Tags: mysql

The `YearWeek` is not working as expected, for me.

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(date_format('2022-01-03','%Y-%m-%d'),1)-1`

The actual results : 202200
Expect the result : 202152
```

MySQL version: 8.0.19

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE('2022-01-03','%Y-%m-%d') ,INTERVAL 7 DAY))
```